# Getting error while running SQL query in Procedure in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

Tring to create a simple procedure that takes a input and performs a Select Query as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test3(br IN VARCHAR2)
AS
    a varchar(32);
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM BRANDS B WHERE B.BRAND_ID = br  INTO a;
    dbms_output.put_line(a);
END;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Errors: PROCEDURE TEST3
Line/Col: 5/1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 5/47 PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Table is:

| BRAND_ID | NAME | ADDRESS | JOIN_DATE | PASSWORD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brand01 | Brand X | 503 Rolling Creek Dr Austin, AR | 04/01/2021 | 12345abcde |
| Brand02 | Brand Y | 939 Orange Ave Coronado, CA | 03/25/2021 | 12345abcde |
| Brand03 | Brand Z | 20 Roszel Rd Princeton, NJ | 05/08/2021 | 12345abcde |

Comment: The `INTO` clause (`INTO a`) must come right after `SELECT`, before `FROM` - not at the end of the query. Didn't check to see if there are other mistakes - fix this one first and see what happens.

Comment: I have replaced the SELECT statement to ```SELECT B.Brand_Id INTO a FROM BRANDS B WHERE B.BRAND_ID = br  ;``` 
The procedure is working now. However on calling the procedure I am getting the error as below:
```ORA-00904: "TEST3": invalid identifier```

Comment: OK, and when you tested again, what happened? Did you get what you needed? Did you run into other errors?

Comment: @mathguy , I ran what you said , see my comment above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want the `INTO` clause before the `FROM`.
- You need a `%ROWTYPE` variable with `SELECT *`.
- Following on from the previous point, you cannot use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` on a record; you need to extract the individual fields.
- You should handle the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.
- Do **NOT** store passwords as plain-text. Store a one-way hash of the password.

Which gives:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test3(
  br IN BRANDS.BRAND_ID%TYPE
)
AS
  a BRANDS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO   a
  FROM   BRANDS
  WHERE  BRAND_ID = br;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(
    a.brand_id
    || ' ' || a.name
    || ' ' || a.address
    || ' ' || a.join_date
    || ' ' || a.password
  );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
BEGIN
  test3('Brand02');
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Brand02 Brand Y 939 Orange Ave Coronado, CA 25-MAR-21 12345abcde
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e24329f6c1e6fe697b6fb911a9ff0a5)*